# mobile menu close on clicking menu item JS

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

[image]
this is my HTML code. I want to collapse menu on clicking menu-item through JavaScrip. I am stuck here since two days. Is there anyone to solve it with explanation so that next time I can handle it myself.
Thanks in advance.

I tried much coding for two days but all in vain.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy and paste the code directly into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to this one: https://bootstrap-menu.com/_bootstrap4/detail-offcanvas-collapse.html

Grab every menu item and toggle navigation on click event:

```
<script>
        const navItemsHandler = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');
        const navMobileHandler = document.querySelector('.js-nav-toggle');
        const navIcon = document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler-icon');
        navItemsHandler.forEach((element)=>{
          element.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            if(navMobileHandler.classList.contains('show')){
              navMobileHandler.classList.remove('show');
            }
          });
        });
        navIcon.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
          if(!navMobileHandler.classList.contains('show')){
              navMobileHandler.classList.add('show');
            }else{
              navMobileHandler.classList.remove('show');

            }
        })
    </script>
```

First of all, grab all navigation items, which should listening on click events. On click event of these items check if navigation is showing, if is - remove bootstrap 'show' class. Also on 'navbar-toggler-icon' click event add similar condition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am new to JS and need complete code with explanation. so that I may be able to understand it.

Comment: Check now, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: 'bootstrap is not defined' is returned if you import bootstrap older than 5.0